# How do I convert the result of individual result vectors to a long vector in R

Tags: r

say I have the following sapply call which results in the following:

```
> sapply(1:3,function(x) (x+3):(x+x))
[[1]]
[1] 4 3 2

[[2]]
[1] 5 4

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
[1] 4 3 2 5 4 6
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Read the help file for `unlist` or `do.call`.